# JSOUP behaviour differs when move application to other server. Why 404 error?

Tags: java, http, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jsoup

I searched for solution, but may be look in wrong place. 
I create Jsoup request and it works on one computer, but not works on other. I checked with other requests - they works fine on both. How to detect what happen ?

So I create application and put in main method one JSOUP call

```
String taskJson = Jsoup
        .connect(
                "https://aaa.com/job_listings/startup_ids?filter_data[last_active]="
                        + "1"
                        + "&filter_data[roles][]=" + "Marketing"
                        + "&tab=find")
        .timeout(10000).
        userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0")
        .ignoreContentType(true).execute().body();
```

And it works fine on my Win 7 PC, and Debian PC. But when I try to run it from other Windows 2008 server (Amazon AWS EC2) I get

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=https://aaa.com/job_
listings/startup_ids?filter_data[last_active]=1&filter_data[roles][]=Marketing&tab=find
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:537)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
        at AngelJSOUPCheck.main(AngelJSOUPCheck.java:16)
```

Well. I thought may be something wrong with server settings, and check request to login form on same domain. It works perfect.

```
Response getLoginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://aaa.com/users/login")
                .timeout(10000)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0")
                .method(Method.GET).execute();
```

Please note that broken request takes data from not secured area

UPDATE:

I tried to get data from URL with HttpURLConnection - and get: IOEXception file not found, when tried get stream with website data.

My next try was with proxy. And I was able to get data with HttpURLConnection object. Then I installed Firefox and it states 404. I cleaned cookies for IE, and it also states 404.

Looks like target website checks for IP, and if it somehow not trusted, needs cookies to be wired to request. While requests from other locations not need them. May be will check this later...

Comment: I just tested your code on my box and got a connection timeout. Maybe the service is temporatily down...

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I replaced domain name to be secured, so actually it is other domain.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the webserver in question blocks IP addresses from Amazon AWS EC2 service. To check this, you could try to use curl or wget in a shell to get the contents from the AWS machine. If that fails too, you can try using a proxy to access the website and see if that helps.

Comment: I can get data from broken URL in Internet Explorer on same AWS Windows 2008 server instance. should I still look for curl or wget?

Comment: No, if you can get it with IE within the AWS instance then JSOUP should be able to get tit as well. I have no idea what else could be the problem - sorry.

Comment: @Pavlo Did you try to use another User Agent string?

Comment: Hello, yes, I tried to change user agent but no luck. I checked with proxies and my script works. I think my target website just check IP and AWS IP was somehow untrusted. So there is not a JSOUP problem as I thought before.